# How is the "scss" directory generated in my ASP MVC .net application?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sass

I use Visual Studio 2019 to develop a web ASP.NET MVC application.

When I debug, or execute my web application, with the browser debugger <kbd>F12</kbd>, I can read in the sources menu (view photo) that my pages are based on sccs style sheets located in a scss directory.

How to generated this directory? Why most of the css (coming from bootstrap) are translated into sass files ? Is it due to the package Web.Optimization  which generate bundles? I don't understand the process and its utility.

Can someone answer my questions ?

For information, I installed bootstrap 4.5.3 with NuGet, and I noticed that several files where created in"Content" directory in the project explorer (bootstrap-grid.css.map, bootstrap-reboot.css.map, etc). So I think bootstrap is maybe the reason of scss files like _reboot.scss).

[image: scss files generated in scss directory]

Answer (score 0):

Scss files are translated (by engine [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/)) into css. Only that files browser can understand.

I think files from picture are just in public folder.

(*.map, *.min.css, etc) files are optional.

In Bootstrap documentation is written:

> compiled and minified CSS and JS (bootstrap.min.*). CSS source maps (bootstrap.*.map) are available for use with certain browsers' developer tools

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#whats-included-precompiled

The minimized files are size optimized and maps are helpful for developer tools use.

Comment: I progress in my thinking . I deleted all bootstrap files (*.map, *.min.css, etc) and I kept only bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js....and my web application still works !! With F12 key in Edge, my styles are now based on the css bootstrap.css. SO all these deleted files were useless.... Can someone explain me why ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. So if you don't want use minified styles you don't need maps neither.

Comment: To better understand the presence of the files .map which are used to debug web appli, read [Use_a_source_map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Apan.

Finally, I can keep only the 2 files bootstrap.css and the js, because MVC minimizes  them with bundling process.